Proxy doesn't redirect all trafic through vps server
I set up shadowsocks on my vps, and connected to it from my computer.
Now, I'm under the proxy, and expecting that the only ip address that my computer makes requests to is my vps server with shadowsocks. To test it I checked destination ip addresses with wireshark and made simple request
wget google.com

and I found out that above command bypasses my proxy ! Has anyone encountered with it?
As a server I use shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev docker container.
Local configuration
{
    "server":["my server"],
    "mode":"tcp_and_udp",
    "server_port":403,
    "local_port":1090,
    "password":"my password",
    "timeout":86400,
    "method":"aes-256-gcm"
}

This is how I setup proxy on my ubuntu
setting

So that what you are doing can be seen, edit the question and add the configuration of shadowsocks and the ip address and other relevant networking information of the system on which it is running.

Very few applications will support SOCKS proxies out of the box. wget does not. You’d need something like socksify of the Dante project, which redirects sockets over SOCKS. But using that can cause application malfunctions and isn’t 100 % reliable either.
If you want to tunnel everything, a proxy is not a good solution, because it requires applications to actively use it. So your example is not exactly an (active) “bypass” but rather “unknowingly ignored”.
Instead, you should use a virtual private network (VPN). Yes, like NordVPN and whatnot. You can easily host one yourself (with that VPS of yours), and with a reasonable amount of work you can also make sure nothing can bypass it. A VPN does not require any special application support.

I already have wireguard set up as well. But I would like to hide that I use vpn... That's why I came to shadowsocks.

So, proxy doesn't route all traffic like VPN. That's what I was looking for
